# Load a Website URL from a textbox in a window in Swish Max 3

Tags: flash, url, swish

Thanks for reading in advance.

I am making a dummy mobile screen where a user should type a URL in a textbox and the url shall be loaded in a mobile window. I have made all the designs. But can somebody please suggest how to do that please.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the textbox content via its `text` property. If you are using a normal text input field named **myTextBox** :

```
var myUrl:String = myTextBox.text.trim(); // Use trim to strip white spaces!!
getURL(myUrl, "_blank");
```